# jQuery - Hide & Show Element REVERSE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got this code off the internet and I'd Like it reversed so the Element is hidden and a button is pressed to show it.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#hide').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input onclick="change()" id='hideshow' type="button" value="Hide">
<div id='hide>
*content here*
```

So basically i'd like it reversed if possible. So the Element (div) is hidden, and the button (input) is clicked to show it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hide').hide();
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#hide').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5LSG5/7/)

Comment: @downvoter please put comment for ur vote?

Comment: No need to downvote, this is a perfectly valid approach.

Comment: @downvoters  No problem for your vote ,If you have any opinion then put your comment , It will help to me and others

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jQuery:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $divHide = jQuery('#hide');    
    $divHide.hide();
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
         $divHide.toggle();
    });
});
```

But I'd recommend you do it with CSS (with your jQuery in tact as it is now):

```
#hide
{
   display: none;
}
```

I recommend this approach because Javascript executed on DOM ready can sometimes be visible to the user. Meaning your `#hide` div will be visible initially (if only for a split second).

*Also (as an aside), I'd rethink the naming convention a bit. I wouldn't call a div 'hide', especially when, on occasions, you'll want it to show.*

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` was deprecated, you should use `.on()` instead, and also use `.toggle()`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('body').on('click','#hideshow', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#hide').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input onclick="change()" id='hideshow' type="button" value="Hide">
<div id='hide' style="display:none;">
             ^ check for this apostrophy
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#hide').show();
    });
});
```

.live doesn't get used anymore and got removed from the jquery api on version 1.9. So to ensure compatibility with newer versions you should use the on method instead (http://api.jquery.com/on/)
If you want to toggle the element, keep using

```
jQuery('#hide').toggle("show");
```

.show(); will only show and not hide it

Answer (score -2):

**Jquery** (replace `live` by `on`):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#hide').toggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML** (add a single quote at the end of `id='hide'` and the closing tag `</div>`):

```
<input onclick="change()" id='hideshow' type="button" value="Hide">
<div id='hide'>
  *content here*
</div>
```

**CSS** (add this css rule):

```
#hide {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to trigger `$("#hide").show();` on clicking on button element.

**HTML Code**

```
<input id='hideshow' type="button" value="Hide">
<div id='hide' style="display: none;">
    LoremIpsum
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$("#hideshow").click(function(){
    $("#hide").show();
});
```

Comment: Then how does he hide it again? You've taken away the `toggle` he'd written.

Comment: It was not there in the requirement that we need to display the section on button click

Comment: But you've removed the toggle based on an assumption.